# What are the steps for .net MAUI DevExpress free control use?

Tags: xamarin.forms, devexpress, maui

I am facing this exception while using DEVEXPRESS. Please give me a solution for that.

MainPage.xaml

```
<dxe:TextEdit PlaceholderText="Email Address" 
     PlaceholderColor="Gray" FocusedBorderColor="#f96332" 
     BackgroundColor="White" CursorPosition="2" 
     HeightRequest="40" Text="{Binding Email}" TextColor="DarkGray" />
```

I've added DevExpress.editor nuget

[image]

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000173
> from typeref (expected class 'Microsoft.Maui.IMauiHandlersFactory' in
> assembly 'Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null')'

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Where is the relevant code?  What are you doing that triggers this exception?  Which nuget packages are you using?

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/403249/get-started IMPORTANT: See instructions to “register this package source”.

Comment: Please make sure that you have installed Microsoft .NET MAUI Preview 11 as per https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases/tag/6.0.101-preview.11.3.

Then, install the latest version of DevExpress .NET MAUI packages from nuget.devexpress.com (they are compatible only with Preview 11).
If this does not help, please submit a new question using the DevExpress Support Center (https://devexpress.com/ask).

Comment: @DennisGaravsky,I have update my preview version but still I'm facing this above exception .

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this  issue using :--Add handler on your `MauiProgram.cs` and used followinf name space in our Xaml
for using editor control

xmlns:dxe="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Editors;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Editors"

```
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                   {
                       handlers.AddHandler<DXCollectionView, DXCollectionViewHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<ChartView, ChartViewHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<PieChartView, PieChartViewHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<DataGridView, DataGridViewHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<SimpleButton, SimpleButtonHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<TextEdit, TextEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<CheckEdit, CheckEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<NumericEdit, NumericEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<PasswordEdit, PasswordEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<MultilineEdit, MultilineEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<ComboBoxEdit, ComboBoxEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<DateEdit, DateEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<TimeEdit, TimeEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<AutoCompleteEdit, AutoCompleteEditHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<TextEdit, TextEditHandler>();
                       //handlers.AddHandler<DrawerView, DrawerViewHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<InputChipGroup, ChipGroupHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<TabView, TabViewHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<DrawerPage, DrawerPageHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<TabPage, TabPageHandler>();
                       handlers.AddHandler<PasswordEdit, PasswordEditHandler>();
                     
                   })
```